# How to make Google Spreadsheet editable only at specific times

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I want to create a Google Sheet, where multiple users can insert the name of the company asset they are checking out for the night on one column and get approval from their manager on another column. I would like to restrict access so that the last entry is at 7PM every day, so essentially, "lock" that day's data. The following day, staff can add new rows with new data but cannot edit / add anything in the previous day's data.

Is there a way to make this function of "locking" and "unlocking" the document automatic?

Comment: There are several ways to do this by using a script, like editing the list of spreadsheet editors or by protecting a sheet/range and editing the list of editors. By the other hand the question doesn't include any details about the search/research made. Please checkout [ask] and add more details.